# Controlling Kafka-Offsets using KafkaItemReader and writing to a Database

Tags: spring-data, spring-batch, spring-kafka

I'm using the following libraries:

- spring-boot 2.5.8
- spring-kafka 2.7.9
- spring-batch-infrastructure 4.3.4 (including `KafkaItemReader` and `JdbcBatchItemWriter`)

I defined a job that **reads items from a Kafka-topic** (with a defined chunk-size) and **writes them to a database**. Simplified code:

```java
@Bean
@StepScope
KafkaItemReader<Object> myReader(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
    return new KafkaItemReaderBuilder<String, Object>()
            .consumerProperties(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties())
            .partitions(0)
            .partitionOffsets(new HashMap<>())
            .topic("myTopic")
            .build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
ItemWriter<Object> myWriter(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Object>()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .sql(QUERY_INSERT)
            .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
            .build();
}

@Bean
Step myStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, KafkaItemReader<Object> myReader, ItemWriter<Object> myWriter) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep")
            .<Object, Object>chunk(1)
            .reader(myReader)
            .writer(myWriter)
            .build();
    }
```

When I put 2 items to the Kafka-topic and using **chunk-size 1** there are the following method-calls:

1. `KafkaItemReader.update()` (initial call)
2. `KafkaItemReader.read()` (first Kafka-item)
3. `JdbcBatchItemWriter.write()` (first Kafka-item)
4. `KafkaItemReader.update()`
5. `KafkaItemReader.read()` (second Kafka-item)
6. `JdbcBatchItemWriter.write()` (second Kafka-item)
7. `KafkaItemReader.update()`
8. `KafkaItemReader.close()` (closing the reader)

The method `KafkaItemReader.update()` looks like this:

```java
@Override
public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
    if (this.saveState) {
        executionContext.put(TOPIC_PARTITION_OFFSETS, new HashMap<>(this.partitionOffsets));
    }
    this.kafkaConsumer.commitSync();
}
```

After the first read item from the Kafka-topic the call to `KafkaItemReader.update()` (step 4 in the above list) commits the whole offset (+2, because the job read 2 items) because of `this.kafkaConsumer.commitSync();`.
So when I receive an error in method `JdbcBatchItemWriter.write()` in the 2nd chunk, the 1st chunk is written to the database and the 2nd is not (that's correct behaviour).

**The problem**:
When the next job-execution starts I can't re-read the 2nd chunk, because the offsets are already committed.
So I want to commit the offsets only for the successful processed (read and write) chunks.

The only solution I have, is to manually control the offsets (i.e. using a database table) for each partition:

- Replace the `new HashMap<>()` in `.partitionOffsets(new HashMap<>())` with the information from the table
- Update the offset information in the table after each successful processed chunk

**Question**:
Is there another approach/way to synchronise these two transactions (reading from Kafka, writing to database)?